# How can I instantiate a base class and then convert it to a derived class?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, casting

I was wondering how to do this, consider the following classes

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
public class Apple : Fruit
{
    public Apple()
    {

    }
}
```

How can I instantiate a new fruit but upcast to Apple, is there a way to instantiate a bunch of Fruit and make them apples with the name & color set. Do I need to manually deep copy?

Of course this fails

```
Fruit a = new Fruit();
a.Name = "FirstApple";
a.Color = Color.Red;
Apple wa = a as Apple;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Apple name: " + wa.Name);
```

Do I need to pass in a Fruit to the AppleCTor and manually set the name and color( or 1-n properties) Is there an better design to do this?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this?

Comment: @welbog, prolly never want to ;) it is just showing a flaw in our design, fruit acts as a template, apples extends it, and other wokers use fruit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In your model, a `Fruit` is not an `Apple` - if you want an `Apple`, instantiate one.** Alternatively, if you want to create an `Apple` using a `Fruit` as a starting point, create a constructor for `Apple` that can accept a `Fruit`.

You should note, that object models where intermediate classes in the inheritance hierarchy are instantiable (not abstract) is often a bad idea. In some cases, such hierarchies may be appropriate - but I've found that in general they are more trouble than they are worth. Think really hard about whether both `Fruit` *and* `Apple` need to be concrete and instantiable.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't seem right, which says to me this should be redesigned
 public Apple(Fruit fruit)
        {
            base.Color = fruit.Color;
            //etc
        }

Answer (score 6):

By default, the `a` instance is an instance of `Fruit` and is not convertible to `Apple`. It's **not** an `Apple` instance, and will never be.

You can, however, implement an [explicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to come up with a way to instantiate one of many possible objects derived from a common base class.  Typically this is done through the Abstract Factory pattern.  For more details and implementation examples see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: What's wrong with this answer?  I thought it'd be a good resource for the OP.

Comment: Answers that are just links are frowned upon.

Comment: That's a fair cop.  Relatively new here, apologies.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a Fruit, it isn't an Apple.  You can't upcast it, because it probably won't have all of the attributes that it'll need.  If you want an Apple, create an Apple.  You don't need to pass anything to anything.

I suspect the following will work:

```
Fruit a = new Apple();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Apple name: " + a.Name);
```

...but I'm not a Java programmer.  That's basically what you'd do in C++ though.  (Be sure to read the Abstract Factory Pattern link given in another answer, especially if you need to instantiate a bunch of different subtypes of Fruit.)